# Connecting Android App with Broker shiftr.io

Tags: android, mqtt, iot, paho

I have a challenge, i am unable to successfully connect an app which I developed in Android Studio IDE with broker shiftr.io [https://cloud.shiftr.io](https://stackoverflow.com) using my account.

Using the the app, though i could connect to the public account
using these configurations:

```
 final int mqttport=443;
 final String mqttpwd="public";
 final String mqttuser="public";
 final String mqtthost="wss://public.cloud.shiftr.io";
```

but using account which i created, that is yet to be a success.
From the broker's token generation, the short Note clearly states, for individual accounts.

```
final String mqttpwd="mqtt://tracker:"**token**"@tracker.cloud.shiftr.io"; 
final String mqttuser="tracker";  //name of the instance
final String mqtthost="tracker.cloud.shiftr.io:1883";  //
```

I am very sure there is something i am missing/mixing up.
I wish someone can point to me while I appreciate your helping hands.

Comment: I eventually got it worked. 


final String mqttpwd="token";
final String mqttuser="tracker";
final String mqtthost="tcp://tracker.cloud.shiftr.io";